# python filter distinct dictionary key value in list

Tags: python

I have a list like :

```
lis = [{"class":"math","teacher":"Joe"}, {"class": "english","teacher":"Marry"}, 
   {"class": "history","teacher":"Anne"},{"class": "history","teacher":"Bob"}
    {"class": "math","teacher":"Cathy"}]
```

And I want to find the distict `class` (how many class in the list )  :

```
['math','english','history']
```

How can I do it  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

print(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(map(itemgetter("class"),lis))))
['math', 'english', 'history']
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use set comprehension (given that you use Python >= 2.7.6) and if the order doesn't matter:

```
distinct_class = {element['class'] for element in lis}
print list(distinct_class)
>> ['history', 'math', 'english']
```

Comment: Well I assume that it's not since OP didn't say that it did :) I will edit my answer to reflect that this way has no sense of order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to iterate over the items and append them to a list if it is a new class type.

```
distinct_classes = []

for dist in lis:
    if dist['class'] not in distinct_classes:
        distinct_classes.append(dist['class'])

print distinct_classes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set comprehension to build a set from your list, extracting the `class` attribute of each `dict`:

```
>>> {x['class'] for x in lis}
{'history', 'english', 'math'}
```

You can convert this set to a list, if needed, using `list()`.

If you want to preserve the order when removing duplicates, then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)